# Jinja if statments

Tags: python, jinja2

Hopefully someone can help me here..

Lets say I have column a, this column 'a' can have rows of all values. I need to get jinja to look at the data of this row and if it's below a specific value, to change the html (Lets not worry about that)

The below works fine. Both rows of data display as needed.

```
<table>
    {% for row in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ row['a'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row['b'] }}</td>
</tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

How can I say for example:

for value in row a, if it's less than 50, do this, else, do this.

UPDATE: Can anyone see an issues with the following?

```
<table>
{% for row in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ row['a'] }}</td>
    {% if row['b'] <= 10 %}
    <td><font color="#FF0000">{{ row['b'] }}</font></td>
    {% else %}
    <td>{{ row['b'] }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    <td>{{ row['c'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row['d'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row['e'] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: And is `row['a']` a string or an integer?  Presumably you already tried an `{% if %}` construct but it didn't work for you?

Comment: Hi Martijn, row['a'] is a integer. I tried: 

`   {% if row['a'] <= 10 %}
    <td class="test"> {{ row['a'] }} </td>
    {% else %}
    <td> {{ row['a'] }} </td> `

But this didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation of condition would be like this, You need to close the if block in the template.

```
    <table>
    {% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        {% if row['a'] <= 10 %}
        <td class="test">{{ row['a'] }}</td>
        {% else %}
        <td> {{ row['a'] }} </td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Seems like the value condition itsnt working. Even when setting to a fixed value like == 4 which I know is inside my data. Everything prints out with normal TD tags.

Comment: are you sure that `row['a']` is `int` type? try `{% if row['a']|int <= 10 %}` tag.

Comment: Just added a quick update into first post, tables have changed slightly, but logic is still apparent.

Comment: could you explain how the | int <= 10 worked? I would like to understand why. Thaanks.

Comment: It worked because `row['a']` was not a integer. so you have to use a [Filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#filters). [int](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#int) is a [built-in](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) filter that converts a value to integer.